# Executing commands with PHP exec

Tags: php, shell, exec

I am working with one of my projects. I am using XAMPP on my windows machine to develop the project.
Here is the problem I am facing. I need to exec a shell script on the server and display the result on a webpage.The problem is that most of the script is functioning as expected but I am not able to get the output of the following commands,

> ls, cat, pwd

as these commands return me a blank array.

I am not able to find the exact problem.

Comment: You are aware different OSes have different shell commands, right? Just saying, you don't specify what does your server run, but perhaps it is your windows/unix mix what is causing trouble.

Comment: I am developing on my PC which is windows based, but it needs to be implemented eventually in a *nix environment.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I felt it was important to point out that the functionality of `ls`, `cat` and `pwd` can be simulated within PHP, so if all you're doing is calling those commands and passing the results back into PHP, then there might not be any point in calling them at all.

`ls` is a directory listing. PHP provides a class called [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) that can do exactly this in just a few lines of code:

An example:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($directory);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        print "File: ".$fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
```

`pwd` gets the current directory. PHP has a built-in function [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) that does this in a single line of code.

`cat` prints files (and pipes) to the output buffer. This can probably also be done inside PHP. `cat` is sometimes used for some fairly complex command line stuff which you may want to keep in the shell. But for simple stuff (and even moderately complex), PHP is perfectly capable.

It would help to have known more about what you're trying to achieve, but I believe PHP is capable of what it sounds like you're doing without having to use the shell at all.

Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, i will try to consider this, but for this I have to rewrite my shell script. I just needed a way to execute that shell script remotely and display the contents in a graphical format.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) instead of `exec()`.